# How do I return the next item in an array with find()?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to return the next item in the array, that is the element that is next in the index so if I use 7 as an example a below I need to return 8.

```
nums = [5, 3, 7, 8, 1, 10];
num = 7;

const result = nums.find(number =>{
    if(num === number)  // how do I return index+1 here?
      
});
```

so for this example I need to return 8 as this is the next item after 7.  Is this possible to do with find?

Comment: Why do you think [`find`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) is the right tool for this? Use [`indexOf`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) with [property accessors](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

Comment: Thanks, it's pretty obvious now you mention it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use indexOf

```
nums = [5, 3, 7, 8, 1, 10];
num = 7;

const indexOfNum = nums.indexOf(num);
const result = nums[indexOfNum + 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could find direct the next value.

```js
const
    nums = [5, 3, 7, 8, 1, 10],
    num = 7,
    result = nums.find((_, i, a) => num === a[i - 1]);

console.log(result);
```